# CSV parser/reader for C#?

Tags: c#, csv

is there a good and free implementation of CSV parser available under some liberal licence? Some counterpart of [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/) for Java, perhaps a port?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-file

Comment: using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser;

Comment: Not constructive? SO admins are so crazy. This is a VERY helpful question.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[FileHelpers Open Source Library](http://www.filehelpers.net/).

Comment: FileHelpers (for CSV at least) requires that you "define a class that maps to the record in the source (file)", "you must declare a Record Mapping Class" etc. and this is not so hot. I'd like to convert CSV into a DataTable, not knowing in advance how many columns to expect.

Answer (score 53):

There's a nice implementation on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx):

> To give more down to earth numbers, with a 45 MB CSV file containing 145 fields and 50,000 records, the reader was processing about 30 MB/sec. So all in all, it took 1.5 seconds! The machine specs were P4 3.0 GHz, 1024 MB.

Comment: (taking back my +1): I just broke the lumenworks Fast CSV reader on a 53Mb file. Looks like the line caching failed after 43,000 rows and scrambled the buffer. Tried the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParse` and it did the trick.

Answer (score 12):

You can load a CSV file to DataTable.

Sample code -

```
static DataTable CsvToDataTable(string strFileName)
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("DataTable Name");

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\""))
    {
        conn.Open();
        string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + strFileName + "]";
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = 
            new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Make sure you compile your project to x86 processor. It doesn't work for x64.

Comment: this worked pretty well for me since I wanted to stay with the built-in ODBC or OLEDB libraries. Btw, the following has additional code samples for both OLEDB and ODBC: http://www.csvreader.com/csv_benchmarks.php

Comment: This is not working on 64 bit, alas.

Comment: Two links that maybe useful with regards to this answer: 
1. [C# Tutorial - Using The Built In OLEDB CSV Parser](http://tech.pro/tutorial/803/csharp-tutorial-using-the-built-in-oledb-csv-parser)
2. [How To Retrieve Column Schema by Using the DataReader GetSchemaTable Method and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310107)

Answer (score 7):

try [filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) Work amazingly well. I am using it to parse a 100 MB file every day.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the FileHelpers library?  It's free, open source and can be used to parse CSV files.

- http://www.filehelpers.net/

Answer (score 3):

I've started using CSV Parser that is part of the [CommonLibrary.NET](http://commonlibrarynet.codeplex.com/).

It uses .NET 3.5, has an easy API, and convenient overloads/methods & lamda's for iterations.

I don't have any benchmarks for this one like above, but nice thing about this is that it's just one component of a library similar to Java Commons. So I also get a Command-line parser, Repository implementation among other things.