# Splitting a comma delimited text file

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507498/reading-csv-file)

I have a comma delimited file:

```
"Some Text, More Text", 1, 2, 3,4,5,6
"Random Text, text text", 2,4,5,6,7,8
```

```
var content = reader.ReadLine();
var stringArray = content.Split(',');
```

The problem is the text ends up being split into two parts. I want to keep it as one unit. So what are my options?

EDIT: I meant like

Some Text

More Text
1

2

3

4

5

6

I want it like

Some Text,More Text

1

2

3

4

5

6

Comment: (Without being too much of a smarty-wishbone-legs) Please google "C# CSV Reader"... I just did, and theres quite a selection of free ones on offer... including several generations of preceeding questions asked and answered (well) on stack overflow itself. Sigh. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906841/csv-parser-reader-for-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about finding all the matches of this regex:

```
"[^"]*"|\S+
```

Comment: +1 Nice and simple, and good for 99% of (valid) CSV formats you're likely to encounter in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` object, see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f68t4563.aspx

and example of implementation at:

http://www.siccolo.com/Articles/CodeProject/Open_DataSet_From_TextFile/open_dataset_from_text_csv_file.html

This allows me to handle CSV files without worrying about how to cope with whether fields are enclosed in quotes, contain commas, escaped quotes etc.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Regex in Split, so that text in quotes are excluded!

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: ok, got it. You need to use Regex in  Split, so that text in quotes are excluded!

Comment: Dude, for your future reference: Requests for clarification of the question are best posted as Comments on the question (not answers, which they aren't).

Comment: ok dude. point noted. my 2nd comment is not a clarification. its an answer to the question. if you think it doesnt help, let me know, n i will delete the whole answer.

Comment: Edit your answer and move the answer into the answer where it belongs.