# Externally create an excel graph from a CSV file

Tags: c#, excel, csv, graph

I have a bunch of data that I am saving out into .csv (Comma Seperated Value) format.
In excel, I can easily create a bar graph of this by manually selecting the data and hitting Graph.

However, I want to do this externally with a click of a button.

Ideally, I hit a button in C#. This calls a method which generates my .csv file, and then calls an excel function that creates the excel sheet, with the graph created in it.

Not sure how to go about this, or if excel even supports something like this, much less from a csv file!

Thank you.

Comment: Why not open csv in Excel from C#, create graph and then save as .xlsx file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try with [EPPlus library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for creating your excel files directly.

It supports charts and has generally worked great for my projects in the past. The easiest way may be to prepare a "template" file in Excel with blank data (just normal a xlsx file) and insert desired charts and any other required elements. Then you can just open the template file with that library in C#, fill datasheet with data, and save it as another xlsx file with actual data.

Maybe some flag for "recalculation" of data needs to be set, which occurs when the file is opened. Don't know exactly for that library, but it was required for another one I used in the past for xls files.

(I suppose the you already have you data in your application, if not, check those answers for parsing CSV:
[CSV parser/reader for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/906841/127027), [CSV parser/reader for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906841/csv-parser-reader-for-c))

Comment: I've used this library in the past as well, and it works beautifully. Basically, instead of creating a .csv that you open in Excel, it will create a .xlsx for you with the same data. From there, you can create a graph within that .xlsx based on that data.

Answer (score 10):

Further to my comment, here is an example. There is no need to use 3rd Party Libraries. Excel has all the things required to make a chart. Also opening csv is not like opening any workbook in Excel.

For a better understanding, let's create a `sample.csv` and place it in `C:` which looks like this

[image]

Create a new form in C#, place a button and set a reference to the Excel Object Library. Next paste this code in the click event of the button

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            xlexcel = new Excel.Application();

            var xlWorkBooks = xlexcel.Workbooks;

            xlexcel.Visible = true;


            xlWorkBooks.OpenText("C:\\Sample.csv", misValue, misValue, Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                                 Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, misValue, misValue,
                                 misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
                                 misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

            // Set Sheet 1 as the sheet you want to work with
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBooks[1].Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddChart(misValue,misValue,misValue,misValue,misValue).Select();

            //~~> Make it a Line Chart
            xlexcel.ActiveChart.ApplyCustomType(Excel.XlChartType.xlLineMarkers);

            //~~> Set the data range
            xlexcel.ActiveChart.SetSourceData(xlWorkSheet.Range["$A$1:$B$6"]);

            //uncomment this if required
            //xlWorkBooks[1].Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            //xlexcel.Quit();

            //releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            //releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            //releaseObject(xlexcel);
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: This works great. Even from Console App.  I simply had to remove all the "using" except for     `using System.Reflection;` and   `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`.   And by the way, to SAVE the result, use `xlWorkBooks[1].SaveAs("c:\\Sample", XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);`

Answer (score 2):

If you insist in doing it in Excel, you will need to have some kind of library to connect to it. You can either use Office Tools included in VS Pro and better, or use some Open Source library like [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/). Then you can write code like this:

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(<path to csv>);
Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
Excel.Chart chart = ((Excel.ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects()).Add(0, 0, 100, 100).Chart; //the numbers are position and dimensions of the chart
chart.ChartWizard(); // here you have to format your chart, see link below
wb.SaveAs(<output path and format>);
```

Link to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart.chartwizard.aspx).

But I think using something like [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is probably much more straightforward.

Comment: Umm, you are on the right track but it's not that simple to work with csv when you are using Interop. The above code will will put all the data in Col 1 if you use the method `Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(<path to csv>);` You have to either use `.OpenText` method or do a `.TextToColumns`

Comment: You are right, and your answer is obviously more thorough. I upvoted it.