# How to assign values to instances of type T?

Tags: c#, generics

I have some text files that are delimited by commas and I want to read a line, then instantiate it and assign values to the properties. The number of text files will grown in the future but now, I only need to work with a handful of them.

So I created a base class that'll take in a `FileInfo` argument, but the problem is how do I assign values to the instance? At the base class, it won't know what the properties names are. I think I should iterate through the properties and assign them by index, but `t.GetType().GetProperties()` doesn't return any items.

```
public class AccountDataFile : DataFileBase<AccountDataFile.Account>
{
    public class Account
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Type;
    }

    public AccountDataFile(FileInfo fiDataFile) : base(fiDataFile) { }
}
```

base class:

```
public class DataFileBase<T> where T : new()
{
    public List<T> Data;

    public DataFileBase(FileInfo fi)
    {
        this.Data = new List<T>();

        var lines = fi.ReadLines();

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var tokens = line.Split(CONSTS.DELIMITER);
            var t = new T();

            // how to assign values to properties?

            this.Data.Add(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse a csv file?

Comment: @Sayse, yes and then turn each line to an instance of an object.

Comment: Any good reason to reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of correct CSV parsers out there, unlike your sample code that does not handle escaped separators for example...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I'll look into CSV parsers and see if that meets my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the inheriting class provide the implementation:

```
public abstract class DataFileBase<T>
{
    protected abstract T BuildInstance(string[] tokens);
}

public AccountDataFile : DataFileBase<AccountDataFile.Account>
{
    protected override Account BuildInstance(string[] tokens)
    {
        var account = new Account();
        account.Name = tokens[0]; // or whatever

        return account;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid. I would hope I can have a single implementation instead of many.

Comment: @RayCheng This is exactly what I was going to suggest, and it's the cleanest and proper way to solve your problem. If you want to avoid having to repeat this over and over again, you *could* make the base class use reflection to assign tokens to properties (seems flaky IMO), but make it virtual so derived classes can still define their own behaviour if need be.

Comment: @dcastro, but `GetProperties` didn't return any fields, so I can't use reflection to assign values. Any ideas why? But in the debugger, I can see the reflected object and its fields.

Comment: @RayCheng That's because `Account` has no properties :) It has 2 fields however, so use `GetFields` instead. Properties and fields are *not* the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an abstract method to the base class to create the right kind of object.  In your `DataFileBase` add a method like:

```
public abstract T CreateObject();
```

And implement it in `AccountDataFile` :

```
public override AccountDataFile.Account CreateObject() { new AccountDataFile.Account(); }
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I prefer to have a single implementation at the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Consider existing [CSV parser/reader for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906841/csv-parser-reader-for-c) .

If you still want to get your own - many serializers use attributes to do property to field name/column matches. I.e. annotate your `Account` type with [ColumnAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or similar custom attribute and read values at run-time. MSDN have article [Accessing Attributes by Using Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx) covering reading attributes.

```
// starting point to read attributes:
System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(myType);
```