# working with regex and csv quoted strings

Tags: c#, regex

i am trying to convert a string like

```
"test",645,23.4,42,"13,13,14","test"
```

into

```
"test","645","23.4","42","13,13,14","test"
```

i am trying with this code.

```
string pattern = "\",(? !\")";
string pattern2 = "(?<!\"),(? !\")";
string pattern3 = "(?<!\"),\"";
string replacement = "\",\"";

Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
catalogo = rgx.Replace(catalogo, replacement);
rgx = new Regex(pattern2);
catalogo = rgx.Replace(catalogo, replacement);
rgx = new Regex(pattern3);
catalogo = rgx.Replace(catalogo, replacement);
```

but i dont know how to get past the value that already contains commas. `"13,13,14"` since it will change it into `"13","13","14"`

i dont know if thats the best way to convert the string, but at least i believe that it will do the job, just that i dont know why i get past this.

Comment: Did you try to use a TextFieldParser?

Comment: @Steve i dont know what that is, ill look for it, but if you are kind to give me your thoughts on how i could use that i would be gratefull

Comment: my file is being retrieved from a FTP server, and im trying to get that info into a datatable

Comment: I have been using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader for years.  Simple, easy to use.

Comment: I definitely recommend `TextFieldParser` - it's part of the .NET framework and it works well.  I've used it several times (all from C# apps).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSV parser/reader for C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906841/csv-parser-reader-for-c)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev so my question was actually of a regex.. these guys gave me another solution, that doesn't make this a re-post of the solution they suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you need to use a Regex to parse comma separated data.
There are a lot of free libraries specialized in parsing this kind of data and the same NET Framework provides a specific class in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.IO namespace

Here how you could use it

```
string t = "\"test\",645,23.4,42,\"13,13,14\",\"test\"";
StringReader sr = new StringReader(t);
TextFieldParser tp = new TextFieldParser(sr);
tp.Delimiters = new string[] {","};
tp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

string[] result = tp.ReadFields();

foreach(string s in result)
   Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This code retrieves your data and respect the fields enclosed in double quotes avoiding to parse the content of these fields. However it seems that you want also a double quote arounde each string retrieved so you need a second loop to readd the missing quotes

```
for(int x = 0; x < result.Length; x++)
    result[x] = string.Concat("\"", result[x], "\"");
```

By the way, I am not recommending to use this class, free libraries or custom code. To choice between these options is always a tradeoff between costs (write, debug, test, document) and perfomances. If performance is a critical aspect of your solution then you need to test a lot of things using the real data coming from your FTP server. A task that only you could perform.

Comment: i cant use TextFieldParser, i get an error trying to import using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO; i am doing a c# console app.

Comment: This is strange because I have tested this code in a Console application. What error do you get?

Comment: I've used `TextFieldParser` in several C# applications - there shouldn't be any issue with it.  Did you add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO` in your project?

Comment: It would be an act of courtesy (not just for me but also for the Readers) to explain the downvote.

Comment: That has to be the most non-sensical downvote I've seen in my time on this site.....

Comment: it wont let me import the FileIO i get `the type or namespace FileIO does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.VisualBasic`

Comment: added a reference and now i can use it, your example does work, ill try it with my actual code. THANKS!

Comment: @Steve since this will give me an array with all the values how would i read the csv file? i would do this for every line? or is there another way? I need to get this data to a datatable